# LINQ to JSON - SelectToken Error

Tags: c#, linq, json.net, linq-to-json

This is the JSON string that I am working with.

```
string jsonText = "{
    "?xml" : {
        "@version" : "1.0",
        "@encoding" : "UTF-8",
        "@standalone" : "yes"
    },
    "Grid" : {
        "DataRow" : [{
                "DataItem" : [{
                        "@name" : "SYMBOL",
                        "#text" : "005930"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "NAME",
                        "#text" : "Samsung Electronics"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "PRICE",
                        "#text" : "1004.3"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "VOLUME",
                        "#text" : "273.182"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "AGG_VOLUME",
                        "#text" : "302.894"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "DataItem" : [{
                        "@name" : "SYMBOL",
                        "#text" : "AAPL"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "NAME",
                        "#text" : "Apple Inc."
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "PRICE",
                        "#text" : "99"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "VOLUME",
                        "#text" : "32936.4"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "AGG_VOLUME",
                        "#text" : "33078.769"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "DataItem" : [{
                        "@name" : "SYMBOL",
                        "#text" : "MSFT"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "NAME",
                        "#text" : "Microsoft Corporation"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "PRICE",
                        "#text" : "42"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "VOLUME",
                        "#text" : "103441.6"
                    }, {
                        "@name" : "AGG_VOLUME",
                        "#text" : "1324432.074"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}"
JObject feed = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
```

I'm trying to get a list of values for SYMBOL, NAME, PRICE, & AGG_VOLUME.  Here's my code so far:

```
var covg = feed["DataItem"]["@name"].Select(f => (string)f.SelectToken("#text"));
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Lecture 1: how to debug your code... Write smaller codes. `var aaaa = feed["DataItem"]` Then check if `aaaa` is null etc.......

Answer (score 2):

[`JToken.SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) supports [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  You can make use of this syntax to perform the query you require:

- `".."` is the wildcard *recursive descent operator*.  Thus `feed.SelectTokens("..DataItem")` finds the values of all JSON properties named `DataItem` no matter where they are in the JSON hierarchy.
- `"[?(@.@name == 'Value')]"` queries for objects in an array with a property named `@name` with value `Value`.

Thus, the following does what you need:

```
var feed = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

var query = from item in feed.SelectTokens("..DataItem")
            select new
            {
                SYMBOL = (string)item.SelectToken("[?(@.@name == 'SYMBOL')].#text"),
                NAME = (string)item.SelectToken("[?(@.@name == 'NAME')].#text"),
                PRICE = (string)item.SelectToken("[?(@.@name == 'PRICE')].#text"),
                AGG_VOLUME = (string)item.SelectToken("[?(@.@name == 'AGG_VOLUME')].#text")
            };
var list = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `feed` refers to the root `JObject` which does not directly contain a `DataItem` property.  Thus `feed["DataItem"]` returns null.  When you then try to dereference this null expression it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

The data you are trying to get is several layers down in the JSON, so your query has to account for this.  To get a list of all `SYMBOL` values in the JSON, for example, you would need to do something like this:

```
List<string> symbols = 
    feed.SelectToken("Grid.DataRow")
        .SelectMany(jt => jt["DataItem"])
        .Where(jt => (string)jt["@name"] == "SYMBOL")
        .Select(jt => (string)jt["#text"])
        .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jxZGZC